# Fill remaining height sidebar

Tags: html, sidebar

So my problem is that my side bar has another colour than the rest of the page.
My sidebar should fill out 100% of the side, with the colour: #1a2327 and #20282b. So it would look like the navigation buttons all the way down to the end of the page.

I've tried settings a `<div>` with height 100% but that didn't seem to work. Also I've tried adding another `<li>` and just styling it differently, also with height 100%, but that didn't work either.

with 100% hight but that didn't seem to work. Also I've tried just adding another

[Here is an image of the sidebar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ul3UH.png)

Some of the html:

```
<nav class="sidebar">
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="faqhtp.php">
            <span class="icon">
                <i class="fa fa-exclamation"></i>
            </span>
            <span class="expanded-link">FAQ & How to Play</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="fair.php">
            <span class="icon">
                <i class="fa fa-link"></i>
            </span>
            <span class="expanded-link">Provably Fair</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="tos.php">
            <span class="icon">
                <i class="fa fa-file-text"></i>
            </span>
            <span class="expanded-link">Terms of Service</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="support.php">
            <span class="icon">
                <i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i>
            </span>
            <span class="expanded-link">Support</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
.sidebar {
height: 100%;
border-right: 1px solid #292c31;
float: left;
color: #fff;
}
.sidebar ul {
display: block;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
.sidebar li {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
color: white;
}
.sidebar a {
display: block;
color: white;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 16px;
background-color: #1a2327;
}
.sidebar a:hover {
color: #FF9A00;
}
.sidebar-name {
background-color: #161d20;
font-size: 18px;
padding: 15px 30px;
text-align: center;
}
.icon i {
width: 65px;
background-color: #20282b;
text-align: center;
padding: 20px;
border-right: 1px solid #FF9A00;
}
.icon i:hover {
color: #FF9A00;
}
.sidebar-mobile-name {
color: #FF9A00;
font-size: 20px;
width: 65px;
background-color: #161d20;
text-align: center;
padding: 20px;
}
.expanded-link {
float: right;
padding-top: 15px;
padding-right: 20px;
padding-left: 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
.sidebar {
width:200px;  
height: 800px;
border-right: 1px solid #292c31;
background:#20282b;
}
.sidebar ul {
width:100%;
height:100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background-color: #1a2327;
}
.sidebar li {
display: block;
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
color: white;
}
```

Comment: That did not work. The three sections (Games, Account, Extras) just expanded far downwards...

Comment: Can you create a working fiddle of your codes, as I could not find games,accounts in your provided codes, but in image it's visible.

Comment: I cannot create a jsfiddle, becuase of the fonts and stuff i'm including. So the sidebar is totaly f*cked when I paste it in there. But you can see the site here: http://80.167.90.224/csgodeadly/index.php

I only have around 25 minutes before I have to go. So there the site will be shut down for about the rest of the day.(Brothers birthday)

Comment: @zerovacpls .sidebar{background-color: #1a2327;} This fills your bottom of your sidebar.

Comment: That fixes some of it. Now I need the same done, but for the icons. Like the little box where the icons are, needs to be expanded down aswell.

Comment: @zerovacpls I didn't get you, to change the background of icon, .icon i{/*remove background or add another which you want*/}

Comment: I want it like this. https://gyazo.com/d87a01894aaa62abe35151a84c981d02

The problem here is that it got a height of 100% and goes down wayy too far.

Comment: Not on my browser and that differs on resolutions of screens. Even you have set width and height of body to 100%, so it surely will take full browser height. For that you have to change your height in px.

Comment: So I would have to set a specific height with px?

Comment: Yes remove height,width from body and set .sidebar in px around 670px and above.